# Catch Exception in Activity when Fragment Throws

Tags: android, exception, android-fragments

So I'm sure there's an easy answer for this one, but I haven't found it online. I'm using a fragment in Android that uses Play Services, and I want to throw any exceptions from using that fragment back to the activity that hosts it so that I can take the appropriate action depending on the activity. Where would I look to figure out how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an interface to allows communication between Fragment and Activity.

Take a look at the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I didn't know how to make listeners, but that'll be incredibly useful.

Comment: I tried, it just has a wait period :P Trying to get it to work now.